# Numpy multiplying one dimension of an N-dimensional matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array `a` with shape `[M, N, 3]`, and a 2D array `b` with shape `[M, N]`. I want to multiply each of the 3 values in the 3rd dimension of `a` by the corresponding value in `b`, which I am currently doing like so:

```py
a[:,:,0] *= b
a[:,:,1] *= b
a[:,:,2] *= b
```

I was wondering if there is a single-line way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a * b[:,:,np.newaxis]` would do it:

```
In [37]: a
Out[37]:
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])

In [38]: b
Out[38]: array([[4, 5]])

In [39]: a * b[:,:,np.newaxis]
Out[39]:
array([[[ 4,  8, 12],
        [20, 25, 30]]])
```

There are other ways to express the same thing, such as

- `a * np.expand_dims(b, 2)`.
- `a * b[..., np.newaxis]`